# How can I read spam mail safely in Gmail?

Tags: security, gmail, spam-prevention

Is there a way to see the spam mail contents in Gmail safely?

Comment: View it on an iPad, iPhone or Android device.

Comment: Unless unmark the email as spam you can safely view the email.  Just don't allow the email to display any external content.

Comment: @Ramhound : You mean , the page with the message 'be careful with this message' is safe. Is it safe?

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed - Yes of course its safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use an alternate browser than your regular one
2. Open a private browsing tab or window - all browsers have them (Chrome calls it "Incognito window", for example)
3. Browse to your spam folder and view messages - do not confirm the "show images" option!
4. Close private tab - nothing got saved to your machine

Comment: Will gmail evaluate embedded JS, or follow identifiable links embedded in an e-Mail by default?

Comment: No - they will not download any resources external to the email, until you expressly permit it, or mark the email as "not spam".

Answer (score -1):

you can use virus total to scan the site or any url here is the url for that [here is the link](https://www.virustotal.com) 
also you can add the extension on your browser of virus total ,which is free for use by google,whenever you want to read a spam mail ,first scan the site using virus total ,it has more than 40 antiviruses to scan the url,if you find the result is fine then you can easily see the spam mail